# How to add extra data OneSignal Push Notification?

Tags: spring-boot, push-notification, onesignal

How to send extra data(such as notification id) using oneSignal in spring boot? I have already send simple notification to android application but I am confused about sending extra data. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send extra data as a map of data using the **data parameter** in their REST API. Refer to the following for more info:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#attachments

After sending the extra data, you can then get it using the relevant methods of OneSignal SDK.

Comment: I think the link's been updated to [https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/push-channel-properties#attachments](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/push-channel-properties#attachments)